# What's a library/framework like Angular or Vue.js that gives me templating and abstractions over events, but is not an SPA?

Tags: web-development

I've used Angular2 extensively and dabbled in a few other SPA frameworks like Vue and React. However, I've found that the thing I like most about these frameworks are things like:

- html templating (so I can evalulate `{{ inline }}` code, use if statements and for loops to hide/produce various elements, etc)
- 'Reactive' binding between variables in the script and template
- Ability to create reusable components
- Various abstractions over raw events
- In angular's case, typescript

In particular, I don't really care for are all related to routing. My applications tend to consist of dozens of different pages, with dynamic navigation and guards. Also, my applications tend to be form-heavy so I have to deal with loading data asynchronously from different sources, which causes a bunch different problems. These problems get easier when I can do more things on the backend.

So, is there a framework/library that gives me the parts I want, but without the SPA parts?

Comment: I code only SPA with Angular, but never use routing. What is not clear to me, though,  is why you think that you couldn't use angular for MPA (a term which I just invented, and who's meaning you have to guess ;-)

Comment: java+tomcat+netbeans and wiring beans to your xhtml documents is really similar to angular from what I can tell.  Only been working in angular for a few weeks, not a designer, but once I grokked how it all works it is extremely similar and thinking of it that way has helped me a lot

Comment: @mawg if I use an angular app for each page, each page would reload the entire runtime, take several seconds to load. Also development would be a big pain because I'd need to run an ng server for each app and have to manage project files for each app/page

Comment: A very valid point (+1). Of course, you only need one copy of the runtime, and it would only cause a delay on the first load of any page. In fact, I can't see how any other framework won't have the problems that you describe. But I look forward to seeing the answer, if any, as this is an interesting question